# iAd content always displayed in portrait using landscape only app

Tags: iphone, orientation, iad

My current app is landscape only.

I display an iAd banner in bottom area of screen. It's showing correctly in landscape mode.

However tapping it, the ad content screen is sliding in from the right when holding landscape right and from the left when holding landscape left. The ad content screen is always displayed in portrait mode. Is there no way to display ad content screen in landscape mode?

Using iOS 6+.

This is similar but seems to deal with acceleration etc. My app does not rotate except between the two landscape modes. (and actually it seems that that topic is about the banner itself, not the opening ad content screen)
[Landscape iAd is showing the portrait graphic in iOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020832/landscape-iad-is-showing-the-portrait-graphic-in-ios6)

Edit: Apple's iAdSuite seems to do the same. The apps support portrait modes too, but in landscape mode, tapping on an landscape ad the opening ad content is in landscape mode.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198
It looks like this is by design(?) hmmm... not pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm it but it just seems that there is no landscape ad content.